# Postgresql suddenly asking me for a password whenever I run createdb or dropdb from terminal

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I just did a reformat to MacOS Mojave and installed PG11. Prior to this, I was never asked for a password to create or delete a database but now I am. Is there anyway to go back to the old setting of skipping the password prompt?

Comment: Sure. Modify `pg_hba.conf` to allow `trust` authentication and reload the configuration files. But don't be too generous with `trust`!

Comment: Hey Laurenz, thanks for the help! Could you recommend a way to reload though? I'm doing `select pg_reload_conf()` within PSQL but it's still prompting me for a password so perhaps I'm not reloading it right. And no worries, this is just for development on this machine!

Comment: Then your `pg_hba.conf` is probably wrong, since you reloaded correctly. Check the PostgreSQL log file for errors. In case of doubt, add the file to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually got it to work by creating a `.pgpass` file at my home directory and added the following line

```
localhost:5432:*:<username>:<password>
```

And it stopped asking me for passwords after that.